# Multi GPU boot fail

Tags: boot, amd-graphics, gpu

First of all I'm new to linux systems. My problem is that whenever I install the AMDGPU-PRO driver to my system, it does not boots. I only get an empty dark purple screen or a flashing dash or sometimes the GNU GRUB screen. 
I have two RX 480 and an older R9 280 in my machine. (Yes, I am mining coins.) They worked well on Windows but I wanted to switch to linux.

So my question: is it possible that the different gpus are messing up the system? (I didn't have time to take out the 3rd card and I can't access the system for 2 more days...)
If yes, switching from the R9 280 to an RX 470 can solve the problem (as it is also based on the Polaris10 GPU), or should I get a third RX 480?

Comment: Is your graphics card compatible with Ubuntu?